# Angular js Route Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, performance

I'm trying to create a navigation menu..... this is how my html looks like.....

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    <script src="~/Scripts/Course/Course-Module.js"></script>
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        hello{{2+2}}
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><span class="navbar-brand">Registration</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#/Courses">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/Instructors">Instructors</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

When i try to run this my web browser console gives me two errors saying.....

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=CoursesController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:7:500
>       at Sb (http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:57:23)
>       at tb (http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:59:66)
>       at http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:303:231
>       at A.link (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
>       at Z (http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:281:137)
>       at A (http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:242:276)
>       at g (http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:210:393)
>       at http://localhost:49516/Scripts/AngularJs.js:206:510

And.......

> GET http://localhost:49516/Scripts/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)

I have already inserted my AngularRoute JS file and AngularRoute Map JS file in my layout page............ This is how my Module js looks like.............

```
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", ['ngRoute']);

registrationModule.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/Courses', {
                templateUrl: '/Templates/Courses.html',
                controller: 'CoursesController'
            }).
            when('/Instructor', {
                templateUrl: '/Templates/Instructors.html',
                controller: 'InstructorsController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/Courses'
            });
    }]);
```

Comment: This is because your controllers aren't defined anywhere. You have to create and include them.

Comment: I also want to point out that AngularJS is actually really useful in pointing out the error description. The very first line of your error code actually links to an AngularJS site that provides a basic description of the error you are receiving.